# Main method works for java, but not scala

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

I have a module in intellij, where I can create main methods in java which run perfectly, but when I create them in scala and attempt to run them, I get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class xxx
```

My project relies on both java and scala classes. What do I need to do to allow scala main classes to run?

EDIT:

As requested, here's an excerpt of the main class I'm trying to run with scala. I know there's nothing wrong with the code because it works when I initialize the code in intellij as a scala project. The problem here is that I started with a blank project, so I don't know what magic intellij did behind the scenes to make the scala main classes run properly.

```
object WebProxyServer extends Logging {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        // implementation

    }

}

class WebProxyServer() {

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the Scala main method that you think should be working? It is always nice to have some code to look at!

Comment: When you run Scala class directly using java/jar, you need to include the scala runtime jars in your classpath. Or use Scala command. Or bundle an assembly using sbt assembly

Comment: @texasbruce, How does one do this in Gradle? Can you make an answer?

Comment: @user3685285 Sorry I am not familiar with Gradle. You will likely need to add scala-library.jar under scala/lib folder to the classpath in Gradle (if you are producing a fat jar or war), or when you run the java command, add `-cp $SCALAPATH/lib/scala-library.jar` where SCALAPATH is the installation path of scala. Or you can just copy that jar to your runtime lib folder

Comment: The quality of the question would be improved if you showed how you tried to run main. I see from a comment on an answer that you're just using the IDE's run menu.

Comment: It might be an IntelliJ problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-13401
Are you using sbt or any other build tool, and if so, does it work with that?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to run Scala code is to create an `object` that extends `App`, like this:

```
object Main extends App {
  println("Hello World")
}
```

Scala will execute all the code in the object when it is created. (The arguments are available in the `args` member of `App`)

To run this from IntelliJ, select "Run->Edit Configurations", then click "+" and select "Application" and fill in the dialog. The drop-down for the "Main Class" parameter should include all objects that extend `App`, so pick the class you want to run. Once this is done, your `Main` should appear on the "Run" menu.

You can have multiple classes that extend `App` and multiple items in the `Run` menu. I use this to debug specific parts of the code from the IDE without having the run the main program.

---

You can also create an object with a `main` method like this:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

Once this is built you can add `Main` as a "Main Class" in IntelliJ as described above. All objects with a `main` method will also appear in the "Main Class" drop-down.

Both approaches are acceptable, but don't combine the two. That is, don't inherit from `App` and then override the `main` method in `App`.

Comment: I have been working with Scala a lot and this is news to me! Thank you.

Comment: @Tim There are two paths here: use `App` and don't write a `main` method (you put the code in the body of the class), or don't use `App` and do write a `main` method. But never both! It sounded to me like you were saying the second path (of not using `App` at all) wasn't recommended. Anyway, I've upvoted your answer in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

To add Scala code to an existing Java module in Intellij, right click on the module name (usually the top level folder in the project view), and click "Add Framework Support", then check Scala in your list of options.

To add Scala code to a new module in an Intellij project, goto File -> New Module, and choose Scala from the list of options.

If your directory structure looks like this:

```
src
|
|-main
  |
  |-java
  | |-....java packages
  |
  |-scala
    |-....scala packages
```

Then don't forget to right click your scala directory in the project view and choose Mark Directory As -> Sources Root

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. I still get the same error

Comment: My scala code builds without error, and Intellisense knows about the classes in the code, so it's not because the project doesn't know about scala at all.

Comment: In the project tree, when you right click the scala object containing the main method you want to run, do you see an option to run it?

Comment: Yup, I see the option to run, debug and everything. That's how I get the error in the question.

Comment: Ok, I repoed your issue.  Check the answer and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're adding the main method to objects, not classes.  The main method needs to be static.  You can add a companion object, which is just an object with the same name as the class, to contain the main method if you want to add a main method to an existing class.

```
class MyApp {
  // bad main method; will not run
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("hello world")
}

// companion object to MyApp class
object MyApp {
  // good main method; will run fine
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: Yes I am. In fact, the same scala file that has my main object runs perfectly in other purely scala projects. I'm guessing intellij does some magic behind the scenes on module initialization that makes pure scala work, but projects that start as blank or java projects won't automatically work with scala. That's why I'm trying to find the "switch"

Comment: Is your scala code in the same module as your java code, or different modules?

Answer (score 0):

first try check the SDK configuration to your IDE and if this cause you error.

```
object WebProxyServer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {}
}
```

then try `extends App` and `override` your `main(args: Array[String])` if needed

Comment: if you `extends App`, you're not supposed to `def main` at all, you just put the code in the body of the class.